# Passing pointers as arguments and cleaning up

Tags: c++, windows, pointers

My code looks like this:

```
Function()
{
    struct* str = NULL;
    SomeFunction(&str);
    //continue using str
}

SomeFunction(struct** input)
{
    struct* temp = NULL;
    FillInStruct(&temp);
    *input = temp;
    WTSFreeMemory(temp);
    return;
}
```

So I was expecting that after I cleanup temp, my input pointer should become invalid too, and in the first function, I shouldn't be able to use my str pointer anymore, since it's cleaned up. but that's not happening, and I don't really know why. I cleanup my temp pointer but my input and str pointers are still pointing to the correct structure and I'm able to continue using those pointers. any ideas why? would *input = temp; do some sort of copying?

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know what `FillInStruct()` or `WTSFreeMemory()` do, and we don't know what "cleanup temp" means... surely you think that at least something here must be obvious, but if you don't go through the effort of making the necessary details abundantly clear, you are asking for answers from people that haven't got the information they need - meaning most people will just move to the next question, some will point out this flaw, and some will actually give you an answer (which may be useless since they have to speculate on what you mean). Clear communication is essential in our world.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem when you replace `FillInStruct` and `WTSFreeMemory`. For example, you could replace them with `new` and `delete`. If the problem doesn't occur anymore, then those functions are at fault

Comment: WTSFreeMemory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: FillInStruct: using WTSEnumerateSessions to get all windows sessions. but shouldn't matter.

Comment: You probably just have undefined behavior using data after freeing its memory, and it accidentally works for you.

Comment: What do you mean with "that's not happening"?

Comment: [Appearing to succeed is a valid form of undefined behavior, but it’s still undefined.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110929-00/?p=9523)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freeing memory in C++ doesn't do anything to the pointers that may point to it.  So your "input" pointer (aka "str" in Function()) will point to freed memory after SomeFunction() returns.  The contents of that memory after it is freed, and how long it remains in a usable state, is completely compiler-dependent and somewhat random.  Some compilers (like Visual C++) will fill freed memory with a pattern in a "Debug" build, to make it easier to catch these kind of errors, but only if you are using the standard C/C++ operations (malloc/free/new/delete).

Garbage-collecting languages like Java and C# (and a host of others) generally do not have this ambiguity and source of errors.  Is there a reason you need to use C++?

I would suggest an approach that returns the value by copying it into an object instead of returning a pointer.  I don't know what your "struct" is, but let's call it "X":

```
Function()
{
    X thing;
    SomeFunction(&thing);
    //continue using thing
}

SomeFunction(X* input)
{
    X* temp = NULL;
    FillInStruct(&temp);
    *input = *temp;  // copy whole object not just pointer
    WTSFreeMemory(temp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: "Garbage-collecting languages like Java and C# (and a host of others) generally do not have this ambiguity and source of errors." at a cost of determinism, leading to another family of bugs. You can't win.

Comment: Not entering this flame-bait

Comment: @Wheezil You can always remove your own "flame-starter" from your answer, it doesn't add much to the answer anway

Comment: @Wheezil suggesting that someone change their programming language (without any indication that such a thing is going to be reasonable for them) is pretty unreasonable. If you think he's providing flame bait, you should probably keep your gasoline out of general reach.